# Error while using Git on Windows7

Tags: git, bash

Having an issue with Git install on windows7.  Running in bash window. I cd to my wamp folder.
git init randproject
everything is fine.

Now the problem is when I go to create a file under my project it throws an error that the command can not be found.

steps:
create file1.txt
(error)

sh.exe": create: command not found

Does anyone know what is going on... 
git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't have anything to do with git. `create` is not a command in sh(bash shell). I think you should use `touch file1.txt` to create a blank file.

Comment: that would be it. Thanks man